# oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement

Tags: java, spring, prepared-statement, oracle12c, callable-statement

I am using spring 4 and with oracle (ojdbc7.jar) using eclipse

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;    

getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(
            "call AU_CITY (:P_CITYID, :P_DISTRICTID,:P_INACTIVE,:P_CITYNAME,:P_USERID, :RET_ID)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    OracleCallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) ps;
                    cs.setLong("P_CITYID", $list.get(i).getCityId());
                    cs.setLong("P_DISTRICTID", $list.get(i).getCityId());
                    cs.setLong("P_INACTIVE", $list.get(i).getCityId());
                    cs.setLong("P_CITYNAME", $list.get(i).getCityId());
                    cs.setLong("P_USERID", $list.get(i).getCityId());
                    cs.registerOutParameter("RET_ID", OracleTypes.BIGINT);
                }

                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return $list.size();
                }});
```

Exception

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement
```

Comment: not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Where is `ps` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement cast exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096036/oracle-jdbc-oraclecallablestatement-cast-exception)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942763/classcastexception-oracle-jdbc-oraclepreparedstatement